# Taylor expansion - How can we deduce that?

Tags: differential-geometry

We have that $$\tilde{E}=\frac{u^2}{r^2}+\frac{Gv^2}{r^4}, \ \ \tilde{F}=\left (1-\frac{G}{r^2}\right )\frac{uv}{r^2}, \ \ \tilde{G}=\frac{v^2}{r^2}+\frac{Gu^2}{r^4}$$ and that $$u^2(\tilde{E}-1)=v^2(\tilde{G}-1)$$

By considering the Taylor expansions of $\tilde{E}$ and $\tilde{G}$ about $u = v =0$, I have to deduce that $$G(r, θ) = r^2 + kr^4 + \text{ remainder }$$ for some constant $k$, where $\text{remainder}/r^4$ tends to zero as $r$ tends to zero.

By the Taylor expansion of $\tilde{E}$ we get $$\tilde{E}=\frac{u^2}{r^2}+\frac{v^2}{r^4}G+\text{ remainder } $$ and 
by the Taylor expansion of $\tilde{G}$ we get $$\tilde{G}=\frac{v^2}{r^2}+\frac{u^2}{r^4}G+\text{ remainder } $$

Is this correct? How can we deduce that $G(r, θ) = r^2 + kr^4 + \text{ remainder }$ ?

$$$$

---

$$$$

The above is the queston (ii) of the following exercise:

[image]

$$$$

---

$$$$

where the exercise 9.5.1 is the following:

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Please give more information. If you combine your first two displayed equations $G$ cancels, and all you can deduce is that $G$ is arbitrary and that $r^2 = u^2+v^2$. I assume that is what $r$ means but you haven't said. Unless there is more information about $F$ the statement about $G$ doesn't follow.

Comment: I added the whole formulation of the exercise in my initial post... @BobTerrell

Comment: It is not clear how $\tilde E, \tilde F, \tilde G$ are produced. It seems that they come from a reparametrization, but it is not clear what the particular characteristics of the reparametrization are. You should include the whole statement of the problem and exercise 9.5.1 cited in it.

Comment: I had added the whole exercise of which the above is a part... Now I added also the exercise 9.5.1... Could you take a look at it? @AlexM.